# How to force sequential execution of tasks in a separate instances in Activiti workflows

Tags: groovy, activiti, bpmn, sequential-workflow

I want to find a way to execute the script tasks of the separate instances of the same workflow sequentially.

In my case multiple workflow instances are being started on one resource in parallel by a script task basing on some attributes of the resource that the master flow is opened on and the script tasks of those instances are run in parallel, which I don't want. I tried both options of "Asynchronous" flag, but it still executes the script tasks in parallel. For now I'm just saving the duration for sleep() function as variable in the function that starts those instances putting the various values depending on a condition and it basically works, but using it is not the best practice, so maybe some of you, more experienced colleagues will be able to help me finding a "nicer" way to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline signal or message events to signal from one process to the other. On completion of one task in one process, signal the release of the next task in the next process.
Continue until all tasks are complete.